# How to use TestNG in scala sbt framework?

Tags: scala, sbt, testng

I try to start the sample test NG test in the scala sbt framework. I am using below the dependencies.

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVer % Provided,
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % sparkVer % Provided,
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % sparkVer % Provided,
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % sparkVer,
"org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % scalatestVer,
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalatestVer % Test,
"info.cukes" % "cucumber-scala_2.11" % cucumberVer,
"info.cukes" % "cucumber-junit" % cucumberVer,
"junit" % "junit" % "4.12",

"org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.0" % "test",
"org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.1",
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test",
```

[The image is  ExampleSuite class as you can see I am not able to use it correctly[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZhjg.png)

Here is the link I follow up for this case http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_testng_in_scala
 Here is also sbt.version = 0.13.16

Any help really appreciate.

Comment: Please state your question clearly. It is not clear what are you looking for

Comment: I want to use test NG in the scala sbt framework

Answer (score 0):

Add dependencies =>  "org.testng" % "testng" % "6.14.3" % Test, and "create TestNG XML" plugin upload from marketplace  than resolve the issue.